# Spark GraphX - How to pass and array to to filter graph edges?

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am using Scala on Spark 2.1.0 GraphX. I have an array as shown below:

```
scala> TEMP1Vertex.take(5)
res46: Array[org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId] = Array(-1895512637, -1745667420, -1448961741, -1352361520, -1286348803)
```

If I had to filter the edge table for a single value, let's say for soruce ID -1895512637

```
val TEMP1Edge = graph.edges.filter { case Edge(src, dst, prop) => src == -1895512637}

scala> TEMP1Edge.take(5)
res52: Array[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[Int]] = Array(Edge(-1895512637,-2105158920,89), Edge(-1895512637,-2020727043,3), Edge(-1895512637,-1963423298,449), Edge(-1895512637,-1855207100,214), Edge(-1895512637,-1852287689,339))

scala> TEMP1Edge.count
17/04/03 10:20:31 WARN Executor: 1 block locks were not released by TID = 1436:[rdd_36_2]
res53: Long = 126
```

But when I pass an array which contains a set of unique source IDs, the code runs successfully but it doesn't return any values as shown below:

```
scala> val TEMP1Edge = graph.edges.filter { case Edge(src, dst, prop) => src == TEMP1Vertex}
TEMP1Edge: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[Int]] = MapPartitionsRDD[929] at filter at <console>:56

scala> TEMP1Edge.take(5)
17/04/03 10:29:07 WARN Executor: 1 block locks were not released by TID = 1471:
[rdd_36_5]
res60: Array[org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[Int]] = Array()

scala> TEMP1Edge.count
17/04/03 10:29:10 WARN Executor: 1 block locks were not released by TID = 1477:
[rdd_36_5]
res61: Long = 0
```

Comment: I don't know anything about graphX, but your predicate probably always returns `false`, since the type of `src` and `TEMP1Vertex` are different. You should probably do something like `Temp1Vertex.contains(src)` (although I don't know if such a method exists)

Comment: I tried `src == Traversable(TEMP1Vertex)` and `src == Iterable(TEMP1Vertex)` and neither worked, although execution was successful.

Comment: `==` is not strongly typed, mainly for interoperability with java, so it will always compile. However, if you compare objects of different types, it will always return false (unless there is a specific `equals` method defined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that `TEMP1Vertex` is of type `Array[VertexId]`, so I think that your code should be like:

```scala
val TEMP1Edge = graph.edges.filter { 
  case Edge(src, _, _) => TEMP1Vertex.contains(src) 
}
```

Comment: I get the following error `<console>:57: error: value contains is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.graphx.VertexId]`

Comment: Is it required for `TEMP1Vertex` to be of type `RDD[VertexId]`? Is `Array[VertexId]` fine too?

Comment: `TEMP1Vertex` follows the syntax as shown in the question. It can be modified to any type as long as the correct output is returned, but I don't know how it can be converted from `RDD[VertexId]` to `Array[VertexId]`

Comment: I changed `val TEMP1Vertex = TEMPEdge.map(_.srcId)` to `val TEMP1Vertex = TEMPEdge.map(_.srcId).collect()` and turned it into `Array[Long] = Array(-1895512637, -1745667420, -1448961741, -1352361520, -1286348803)` and It worked! Thanks!